# Display the data from 'this.state.data'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
*Get the data of of variable Cars to the 'this.state.data' when you have retrieved the data from API.
*Display data from 'this.state.data' and not using the variable Cars.

Problem:
I do not know how to do it and is is it possible to do it when you have applied refactoring SOLID?

Info:
I'm newbie in React JS.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v39jre?

---

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import CarsList from './components/CarsList';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CarsList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

CarsList.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

this.state = {
  name: 'React',
  data: null
};

const CarsList = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCars = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      );
      setCars(await response.json());
    };
    fetchCars();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {cars.map((car, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          [{++index}]{car.id} - {car.name}$
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarsList;
```

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve you need to call the api - get the data and show it as ul > li structure in render part ? Is that so ??

Comment: I want that data to be located at App.js and not only in CarsList. I want to reuse the data into another component that is for instance CarsList.2jsx

Comment: So you need to do a callback function from child to parent, but instead of calling that api in the CarsList component why don't you call it at the parent component. thats basically called lifting the state approach ?

Comment: Are you meant to be using hooks at all? Because the the question is asking about a React component that doesn't use them, but `carsList` is a function component that does use them.

Comment: "So you need to do a callback function from child to parent, but instead of calling that api in the CarsList component why don't you call it at the parent component. thats basically called lifting the state approach"

It is about refactoring. In this sample you only have CarsList.jsx but in reality you mmight have 6 different CarsList.jsx.

Comment: I have added an answer based on the discussion to get the data from child to parent kindly check. Now the data is available on the parent now you can use it for other components which you required

Comment: I mean it doesn't make much sense. It would be better to load the data in `App` and then distribute that to the various cars lists rather than load it in one car list, send the data to App, and then distribute it.

Comment: "I mean it doesn't make much sense. It would be better to load the data in App and then distribute that to the various cars lists rather than load it in one car list, send the data to App, and then distribute it."

In this context you have 6 different CarsList.jsx  with differnt api call. In other words, not the same api call.

Comment: Yep thats what i have mentioned, thats the common way of using state and sending it to multiple children, @What'sUP Kindly check and let me know. Because in this approach now your other children elements which depends on this data can only be rendered after you receive the  data, even-though a fraction of seconds the other children will show loading but CarsList will get rendered first. So its better to call the Api at your parent component

Comment: @What'sUP Did the answer resolved the issue ?

Comment: But if each car list manages its own API call and state, why are you trying to add that data to the other car lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the response in the child component you should do a callback function which can be passed as prop from parent to child. Using the function you can pass the data from child to parent and update the parent state.

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CarsList from "./CarsList";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  const handleUpdateParentState = (data) => {
    setState(data);
  };

  console.log("state in parent", state);

  return (
    <div>
      <CarsList updateParentState={handleUpdateParentState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CarsList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CarsList = (props) => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCars = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setCars(data);
        props?.updateParentState(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchCars();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ul>
      {cars?.map((car, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          [{++index}]{car.id} - {car.name}$
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CarsList;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-andras-usqt8)

Comment: `setState(data);` won't work if every car list is uplifting its data to the App component. It would have to be something like `setState(prev => ({ ...prev, data }));`. And the question suggests that the OP is meant to use React components rather than functional components.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be shared using props but from parent component to child component only. We cannot pass child component state to parent component through props.

Though we can create a function at parent level and pass it to child component as props so we can execute there.

In your case, you have to create a function in `App` component and pass it on `carList` component as props. In `carList` component you do not have to create the `cars` state. After fetching the cars from API just call the function you passed from `App` component

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import CarsList from './components/CarsList';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: null
    };
  }

  function setCarList(cars) {
    this.setState({
      date: cars
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CarsList setCars={setCarList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**CarList.js**

```
import React, {useEffect } from 'react';

this.state = {
  name: 'React',
  data: null
};

const CarsList = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCars = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      );
      this.props.setCars(await response.json());
    };
    fetchCars();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {cars.map((car, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          [{++index}]{car.id} - {car.name}$
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarsList;
```

Comment: `<CarsList setCars="setCarList"/>` should be `<CarsList setCars={setCarList} />`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense for each `CarList` component to load data if you're going to have loads of them and they're going to share information with each other. You should load all your data in your `App` component using an array of API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) calls and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to extract and parse the data, and then add it to the state. That state can be then shared with all your `Carlist` components.

Here's a React component:

```js
const {Component} = React;

const json = '["BMW", "Clio", "Merc", "Fiat"]';

// Simulates an API call
function mockFetch() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 1000);
  });
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { cars: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Have an array fetches (you would supply each one a
    // different API endpoint in your code)
    const arr = [mockFetch(), mockFetch(), mockFetch()];

    // Grab the json, `map` over it and parse it
    Promise.all(arr).then(data => {
      const cars = data.map(arr => JSON.parse(arr));

      // Then set the new state
      this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, cars }));
    });
  }

  // You can now send the data to your small functional
  // carlist components
  render() {
    const { cars } = this.state;
    if (!cars.length) return <div />;
    return (
      <div>
        <Carlist cars={cars[0]} />
        <Carlist cars={cars[1]} />
        <Carlist cars={cars[2]} />
      </div>
    )
  }

};

function Carlist({ cars }) {
  return (
    <ul>{cars.map(car => <div>{car}</div>)}</ul>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

And here's equivalent written as a functional component with hooks:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const json = '["BMW", "Clio", "Merc", "Fiat"]';

function mockFetch() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 1000);
  });
}

function App() {

  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  // This works in the same way as the previous example
  // except we're not setting `this.state` we're setting the
  // state called `cars` that we set up with `useState`.
  useEffect(() => {
    function getData() {
      const arr = [mockFetch(), mockFetch(), mockFetch()];
      Promise.all(arr).then(data => {
        const cars = data.map(arr => JSON.parse(arr));
        setCars(cars);
      });
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (!cars.length) return <div />;

  return (
    <div>
      <Carlist cars={cars[0]} />
      <Carlist cars={cars[1]} />
      <Carlist cars={cars[2]} />
    </div>
  );
};

function Carlist({ cars }) {
  return (
    <ul>{cars.map(car => <div>{car}</div>)}</ul>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```